# Kotlin json parsing where "val $t: String"

Tags: json, parsing, kotlin, gson

I'm trying to retrieve data from

```
"petfinder": {
    "pet": {
        "name": {
                    "$t": "Belmont"
                }
```

using

```
val currentAnimal = gson.fromJson(body, CurrentAnimal::class.java)
```

and

```
class CurrentAnimal(val petfinder: Animal)
class Animal(val pet: Pet)
class Pet(val name: Name)
class Name(val $t: String)
```

The issue I'm having is that "$t" is not a recognized parameter name.
I tried

```
"${'$'}t"
```

but that just causes more errors. The API I am using has all their data paired with $t so this is a big blocker for me. This is my first time using Kotlin so any help would be awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `$` in identifiers in Kotlin. To specify that the name of the key in JSON is different from the property name in Kotlin, use the `@SerializedName` annotation:

```
class Name(@SerializedName("\$t") val t: String)
```

Comment: Both backticks and @SerializedName work. Thank you both for the help!

Comment: The reason for this is because `$` is used in string templates. It needs to be escaped to work as a string literal instead.

Comment: while I don't find the backticks comfortable to use, it's at least good to know that it works too.

Comment: If you use the backticks, you'll have to also use them every time you reference the name, and the `@SerializedName` solution needs to be applied only once in the class declaration.